# Infer the method type of the API namespace object

Tags: typescript

There are two API namespaces called `user` and `project`. I try to create a generic function that can infer the method type of the API namespace object.

```
const user = {
  async getUser(id: string): Promise<string> {
    return 'user'
  }
}
const project = {
  async getProject(): Promise<string> {
    return 'project'
  }
}
const apis = {
  user,
  project
};

interface UseApiQueryResponse<Data> {
  loading: boolean;
  data: Data | undefined;
}
export function useApiQuery<Params, Data>(api: ??, params: Params): UseApiQueryResponse<Data> {
  return api(params)
      .then((res: string) => ({loading: false, data: res}));
}
```

Customer side usage:

```js
useApiQuery(apis.user.getUser, {id: '1'});
useApiQuery(apis.project.getProject);
```

How can I type the `api` argument, it can be any API method. It is best to infer or constrain the return value type `Data` according to the type of `api`

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJxgXhgbwFAxgQwgE8xgYBzRKAVSWQAoBLAEwC4ZplGxyBKdgArIQAW0ZIAPJ27kAfFlx4YyKnGRgYAcgQpNigL7ZDoSLAAOwgFaJgsDDjyESZSlCEhrt+vxjuxk6R55ByUVKDUNTQsPGyg9PENjcGgCM3F0BTwdZAAaRWjPKCMAbmxsbigUADN8YEQYWkQAQTSARTgUIgAlRAgzZMQJABF8KHxgxQAbEHxmGXYAIxAQScR8MFK8ZlH8dhGxmAAfeDBmRCruRGZSw0QAD37kWCq4UihGcHgkFsZ2zokBPhkPgRBAcjB9uN6Pg0uwAPxw8FmIEgiCCFGgnyNH5-ZDdXr9SCDSETPBhCKpRj0ZHAzGKJQwAB0UAAFogwPR6Co0RwoFweLx0PJ6JhprN5jAapMkODtmN2Nz9LxeDcgA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIrst of all, you need to infer first argument of `useApiQuery`:

```js
type AsyncFn = (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>

const useApiQuery = <Api extends AsyncFn, Data>(api: Api, ...params: Parameters<Api>) =>
  api(params)
    .then((res: string) => ({ loading: false, data: res }))
```

Since, `useApiQuery` returns promise, you can return just `UseApiQueryResponse<Data>` because it will be a `Promise<UseApiQueryResponse<Data>>`:

Also, this line of code `useApiQuery(apis.user.getUser, { id: '1' })` is invalid, because `getUser` expects a `string` and not an object.

Here is the full example:

```js
const user = {
  async getUser(id: string) {
    return 'user'
  }
}
const project = {
  async getProject() {
    return 42
  }
}
const apis = {
  user,
  project
};

interface UseApiQueryResponse<Data> {
  loading: boolean;
  data: Data | undefined;
}

type AsyncFn = (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>

const useApiQuery = <Api extends AsyncFn>(api: Api, ...params: Parameters<Api>):
  Promise<UseApiQueryResponse<ReturnType<Api>>> =>
  api(params)
    .then((res) => ({ loading: false, data: res }))


const result1 = await useApiQuery(apis.user.getUser, '42'); // UseApiQueryResponse<Promise<string>>
const result2 = await useApiQuery(apis.project.getProject); // UseApiQueryResponse<Promise<number>>

export { }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJxgXhgbwFAxgQwgE8xgYBzRKAVSWQAoBLAEwC4ZplGxyBKLXHhjIqcZGBgByBCkmCAvtkWhIsAA7IQAK0TBYGHHkIkylKAAVNOvfX6GhIqGIkAWAEwKl2FdAJrGEOgCeDLIADSCGtq6UEoA3NjY3FAoAGb4wIgwtIgAgv4AinAoRABKiBBq4EgAPAAi%20FD4AHzBMAA2IPjM3OTsAEYgIO2I%20GAJeMyN%20OwNTTAAPvBgzIip3IjMCYrYUERqWbnEpABiEhj0AHTX%20MjkEOxjRADaALr8aK2WIAC2AYg1J7NRI%20WAyfKMIolII1CEwRAADxSK0CRxMZ2a9Hw-nYELCMGulzUt3wPweMHMJJ%20VBQEFh-mavFYgm%20f1qOQhUOQZQqVUgAPKTnEABV9gCIc1JehgUZ-PRichSRBeII8JcoAALRBgej0ETK6UweiYDpdHo8djpdpIfFTJrsfUweS8FUg6qwfVwdpQACMQXwAHd8IwwUhOcVuVj-BBLqFLmYcuEpO5JLw4jAAPQZ7JhwoRnmVaoA1n-GqcXqS7zu4QVL1QNz%20oMh%20C5yH5qMBIlWGLxqjfaxQNOZ7McvMlcqF-k1Eu1MBwH79FCV7CIqrIWAm%20RAA)